# HTML drop-down box with Google App Engine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I am creating a Google App Engine web application written in Python, and I would like to create a drop down box that displays different values corresponding to pages of a book that a user could choose from.  I would like the action of the drop down box to be to direct the user to the page that corresponds to this link:

```
<a href='/viewpage/{{bookpage.key}}'>{{ bookpage.page }} </a>
```

The "bookpage" entity is passed to the html

Thank you!

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Jump Menu](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&q=html+select+jump+menu).  [Here](http://www.entheosweb.com/website_design/jump_menus.asp) is a pretty straight forward implementation.

Basically you'll just add a bit of JavaScript, and instead of writing an a tag, you'll write an option:

```
<option value='/viewpage/{{bookpage.key}}'>{{ bookpage.page }} </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `<option value='/viewpage/{{bookpage.key.id}}'>{{bookpage.page}}</option>`?

I hope it's not a dumb answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the google-app-engine but, the following javascript seems to do what you want.  The python could generate the array variables on the server side, and then everything else would work properly.
I included the hardcoded arrays so you can see what is going on, but you can replace the arrays with the python code(assuming bookpage is some kind of dictionary):

```
i = 0
for bp in bookpage.keys():
    print("mysites["+str(i)+"] = "+ bookpage[bp])+";"
    print("sitenames["+str(i)+"] = "+sitenames[bp])+";"
    i+=1
```

---

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mysites= new Array();
    mysites[0] = "http://www.google.com";   //Generate this line with python
    mysites[1] = "http://www.bing.com";     //Generate this line with python
    mysites[2] = "http://www.yahoo.com"; //Generate this line with python
var sitenames = new Array();
    sitenames[0] = "Google";       //Generate this line with python
    sitenames[1] = "Bing";           //Generate this line with python
    sitenames[2] = "Yahoo";       //Generate this line with python
function changeLink(){
    var index = document.getElementById("theselect").selectedIndex
document.getElementById("thelink").innerHTML=index;
    var newlink = mysites[index];
    var newstring = sitenames[index];
    document.getElementById("thelink").href=newlink;
    document.getElementById("thelink").innerHTML=sitenames[index];
}
</script>
<select id="theselect" onclick="changeLink()">
  <option>Google</option>
  <option>Bing</option>
  <option>Yahoo</option>
</select>
 <br />
<a id="thelink" href="http://www.google.com" > Google </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Clicking on the option box calls the changeLink() function, which then changes the link and the inner html of the  tag.